# Disable character input in dynamically created ComboBoxes and TextBoxes in VB.NET

Tags: dynamic, combobox, textbox, keypress

In a simple program that I am working on in VB.NET, I have created several ComboBoxes and TextBoxes dynamically.

For example, like:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 11
        Dim NewTxt As New TextBox()
        Me.Controls.Add(NewTxt)
        NewTxt.Name = "txtNoteInput" & i
    Next
```

I would like to restrict the user from entering certain keyboard characters into these TextBoxes. I have done this in the past for individual TextBoxes created visually by using "... Handles ExampleTextBox.KeyPress" (Something like described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538.aspx ).

I am looking for help on how to do this: (1) for dynamically created TextBoxes, and (2) with one (or few) blocks of code which apply to many TextBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](http://www.authorcode.com/create-dynamic-textbox-and-label-in-vb-net/) as a reference, something along the lines of:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 11
    Dim NewTxt As New TextBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(NewTxt)
    NewTxt.Name = "txtNoteInput" & i
    ' Add this line below:
    AddHandler NewTxt.TextChanged, AddressOf Text_Changed
Next
```

With:

```
Private Sub Text_Changed(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, _
                         ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs)
    Dim txt As String = eventSender.Text
    ' Do your regular filtering here as you would normally
End Sub
```